# QlikView - How to make a filter in one column and then get the maximum on the other column

Tags: formula, qlikview, qliksense

I am trying to apply a filter in one column `model_number` and then the maximum number of the other filed, `Week`.

This is the formula that I tried.

`=if(WildMatch(model_number,'*4*'),Max(Week,1))`

Does anyone can help me to formulate this?

Comment: If you add the matching into a set analysis inside the `max` function  `max( {<  model_number = {"*4*"} >} Week, 1)`?

Comment: That is it. You are @Stefan Stpichev. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: No problem :) Ill add my comment as an answer as well. SO sometimes clears the comments

Answer (score 0):

You can use [set analysis](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/May2022/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/ChartFunctions/SetAnalysis/set-analysis-expressions.htm) to filter the data.

In your case the expression can be written in this way:

`max( {<  model_number = {"*4*"} >} Week, 1)`

The `max` function will be calculated only on the records that fulfil the condition applied on `model_number` field.